# How to filter multiple values (OR operation) in angularJS with checkbox

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

How to filter multiple values (OR operation) in angularJS with Checkbox

```
<ul ng-repeat="movie in movies |filter:Filter.Comedy | filter:Filter.Action  | filter:Filter.Drama">
    <li>{{movie.name}}</li>
</ul>
<label>Comedy</label><input  type="checkbox" ng-model="Filter.Comedy" ng-true-value="Comedy"  data-ng-false-value=''/><br/>
<label>Action</label><input  type="checkbox" ng-model="Filter.Action" ng-true-value="Action"  data-ng-false-value=''/><br/>
<label>Drama</label><input  type="checkbox" ng-model="Filter.Drama" ng-true-value="Drama"  data-ng-false-value=''/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samibel/va2bE/1/

Comment: Great job clarifying the OR operation. I had been browsing everywhere for something like this.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use a filter function:

View:

```
<ul ng-repeat="movie in movies | filter: showMovie">
    <li>{{movie.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.showMovie = function(movie){
    return movie.genre === $scope.Filter.Comedy || 
        movie.genre === $scope.Filter.Drama ||
        movie.genre === $scope.Filter.Action;
};
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GruffBunny/utKug/)**</kbd>

Comment: @AdamArold can you please explain where you think it doesn't work - have added a fiddle showing it working?

Comment: I'd argue this logic should be implemented in a filter and not a $scoped function.

Comment: This is great! So simple! Appreciate the Example

Answer (score 5):

I've done something similar to this in the past..

```
<ul ng-repeat="movie in ((movies | filter:Filter.Comedy) + (movies | filter:Filter.Action) + (movies | filter:Filter.Drama))">
    <li>{{movie.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This solution is totally fine, as long as genres are assigned exclusive. Otherwise you could get doubled entries of a movie.

Comment: I did operate under that assumption, given that was the case the OP stated.

Answer (score 5):

```
$filter('filter')(data,{type:'x'} && {type:'y'})
```

Will give you all the items which are of type x OR of type y.

Comment: This was exactly I was looking for

Comment: Is Angular gonna RegEx this??? Looks like a Short-Circuit to `type: 'y'`.

Comment: This made my jaw drop, only to find out it doesn't work; at least not in Angular 1.2+

Answer (score 0):

I Have the solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/samibel/va2bE/17/

```
app.filter('searchFilter',function($filter) {
        return function(items,searchfilter) {
             var isSearchFilterEmpty = true;
            //searchfilter darf nicht leer sein 
              angular.forEach(searchfilter, function(searchstring) {   
                  if(searchstring !=null && searchstring !=""){
                      isSearchFilterEmpty= false;
                  }
              });

        if(!isSearchFilterEmpty){
                var result = [];  

                angular.forEach(items, function(item) {  
                    var isFound = false;
                     angular.forEach(item, function(term,key) {                         
                         if(term != null &&  !isFound){
                             term = term.toLowerCase();
                                angular.forEach(searchfilter, function(searchstring) {      
                                    searchstring = searchstring.toLowerCase();
                                    if(searchstring !="" && term.indexOf(searchstring) !=-1 && !isFound){
                                       result.push(item);
                                        isFound = true;
                                        // console.log(key,term);
                                    }
                                });
                         }
                            });
                       });
            return result;
        }else{
        return items;
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: The code breaks at the line which updates `term` value. `term` is undefined. Would love to see that work! I need a custom filter cos I'm pretty sure there's a filter override  on my default `filter:` function.