# Filter of two values for same parameter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

In AngularJS I want to know if it is possible to filter data of a view column using two possible values. So...if I pass a value of a parameter to a page's controller, I want to limit the data to particular values.....

```
Data:
Product        Status
Item 1         Active
Item 2         Planned
Item 3         Completed
Item 4         Cancelled
```

if I want only one value, I can pass routeParams such as filterCol, filterVal like so the following would only show items that are Active:

```
/programs/status/Active/

app.controller('AllItemsController', function($scope,$http,$rootScope,$routeParams){
$scope.tableFilter = {};
    if($routeParams.filterCol && $routeParams.filterVal){
        $scope.tableFilter[$routeParams.filterCol] = $routeParams.filterVal;
    }
});
```

My XML looks similar to:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" ts-wrapper
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ts-criteria="itmName | lowercase">Item Name</th>
            <th ts-criteria="status">Status</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="tableFilter.itmName"></th>
          <th><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="tableFilter.status"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="it in allItemData | filter: tableFilter" ts-repeat ">
                <td>{{it.itmName}}</td>
                <td>{{it.status}}</td>
            </tr>
     </body>
</table>
```

Now, how can I change the controller if I want to send a value such as 'ActPlan' and to show all items that are Active or Planned? (such as:     /programs/status/ActPlan/)

I think I somehow have to change how $scope.tableFilter is set (by checking the value of $routeParams.filterVal), but I can't figure how to set the tablefilter and couldn't find an example to help me. I tried setting it equal to ['Active, Planned'], but that didn't bring anything up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have several condition, you can just use a filter function, like this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411686/how-to-filter-multiple-values-or-operation-in-angularjs-with-checkbox).

Comment: Thanks. I did end up using something similar to one of those, but had to do some serious rework - so far it seems to be working. Thank you.