# AngularJS filter with or combination

Tags: angularjs, filter

I use AngularJS 1.5.8 and I need a  filter of my user: either with dropdown box (vm.selectedUser) of with text input field (searchEmployeesText):
Only with dropdown box it looks like this and works fine:

```
| filter: {user: {surname: vm.selectedUser.surname}}
```

Actually I dont know which approach to use for both:

```
| filter: {user: {surname: vm.selectedUser.surname or searchEmployeesText}}         (this does not work but only to show what I would neet)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `||` instead of `or` between your conditions.

```
| filter: {user: {surname: vm.selectedUser.surname}} || {user: {surname: earchEmployeesText}}"
```

Also please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411686/how-to-filter-multiple-values-or-operation-in-angularjs-with-checkbox) for combining more conditions.