# How to filter list displayed through ng-repeat with muliple fields using checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a JSON like below:

```
var data = [
{
  "id": 1,
  "name"; "Test1",
  "isPending": "false",
  "isCompleted": "true",
  "isRequired": "true",
  "location": [
    {
      "city": "London",
    },
    {
      "city": "New York",
    }
   ]
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "name"; "Test2",
  "isPending": "false",
  "isCompleted": "false",
  "isRequired": "true",
   "location": [
    {
      "city": "Mumbai",
    },
    {
      "city": "New York",
    }
   ]
}
}

..
..
];
```

I want to have 5 checkboxes filters for fields below:

1. Pending
2. Completed
3. Required

### Cities:

1.Mumbai

2.London

I am displaying the data using ng-repeat.

How to apply filter in AngularJS having checkboxes for multiple fields. Basically it should work as OR operator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter multiple values (OR operation) in angularJS with checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411686/how-to-filter-multiple-values-or-operation-in-angularjs-with-checkbox)

Comment: @user271828 it is not duplicate, its about multiple field not multiple checks for the same field. read it once again