# how to add two filters with or condition in ng-repeat Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

i am using ng-repeate and in my filter i need to use one of the fields in upper bounded list that can not be refrenced by inner select filter , so i need to set filters in html block and not in js file .somthing like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="groupfield in gCtrl.groupingFields">  
        <select ng-options="c.id as c.title for c in gCtrl.columnList | filter : {available:true } || {id:groupfield.fieldName}">  
</select></div>
```

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411686/how-to-filter-multiple-values-or-operation-in-angularjs-with-checkbox

Comment: this can't help cause i need to access groupField item

Comment: post groupfields data

Comment: [{"priority":0,"fieldName":"ACTIVITY_SUBJECT_ID"},{"priority":1,"fieldName":"ACTIVITY_TITLE"},{"priority":2,"fieldName":"COMPANY_ID"}]

Comment: columnList is also needed. or please create plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the filter a custom function. You cannot pass arguments to the actual filter function, so the trick is to create a function that returns the filter function, and pass `groupfield` to that.

```
function MyController() {
    this.customFilter = customFilter;

    function customFilter(groupfield) {
        return function(value, index, array) {
            return value.available || groupfield.fieldName === value.id;
        }
    }
}

<div ng-repeat="groupfield in gCtrl.groupingFields">  
    <select required class="form-control" ng-model="groupfield.fieldName" ng-options="c.id as c.title for c in gCtrl.columnList | filter : groupCtrl.customFilter(groupfield)"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it did not work for me , the first solution failed with this error:Token '{' is an unexpected token ...
and the second one also raised the error: Referencing call, apply or bind in Angular expressions is disallowed!

Comment: i also tried gCtrl.customFilter(c, groupField) without any bind but it did not work due to undefiend value and groupField in CustomFilter function call result

Comment: My bad. It's been a while since I worked with AngularJS. Check my updated answer, I believe it should work now.